# usando ROW() no VBA

Tags: vba

Boa tarde,

Quero multiplicar o valor da quarta célula à esquerda pelo número da linha mas rola um erro quando uso WorksheetFunction.Row(RC[-4]) alguém pode ajudar??

```
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]* WorksheetFunction.Row(RC[-4])"
Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2", "H" & linha)
Range("H2", "H" & linha).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao utilizar `.FormulaR1C1` uma fórmula é inserida no Excel. Então a função VBA `WorksheetFunction` não pode ser utilizada dentro de uma função Excel.

Segue o código para contornar o problema:

```
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]*Row(RC[-4])"
Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2", "H" & linha)
Range("H2", "H" & linha).Select
```

> Obs.:
>   [.Select/.Activate/.ActiveCell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/7690982)
>   devem ser evitadas quase sempre (a não ser para ativar eventos ou
>   outras ocasiões que é possível somente com Select).